# How do I change the color of the turtle, not the pen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How do you change what color the turtle *looks*, not the pen? I want the turtle to draw white on the screen, but if I change the color to 'white' I can't see the turtle anymore. Is there something like `turtle.turtlecolor` or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can disconnect the *color of the cursor* (both outline and fill) from the *color drawn by the cursor* (both outline and fill) using the user cursor definition functions:

```
from turtle import Screen, Shape, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape("turtle")
polygon = turtle.get_shapepoly()

fixed_color_turtle = Shape("compound")
fixed_color_turtle.addcomponent(polygon, "orange", "blue")

screen.register_shape('fixed', fixed_color_turtle)

turtle.shape('fixed')
turtle.color('white')
turtle.circle(150)

screen.exitonclick()
```

This turtle cursor is orange with a blue outline but it draws a white line:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There sure is!

```
turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.fillcolor("red")
```

Now you get a red turtle.

Comment: The color drawn *by* this turtle will be the same as the outline color *of* this turtle cursor.  The fill color filled *by* this turtle will be the same as the fill color *of* this turtle cursor.  I believe the OP is trying to separate these concepts, having what the turtle *looks* like not reflect what the turtle *does*.